# Why does BernoulliNBC perform worse compared to the GaussianNBC or the MultinomialNBC on the iris dataset?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

```
 from sklearn import datasets
 iris = datasets.load_iris()
 from sklearn.naive_bayes import GaussianNB, MultinomialNB, BernoulliNB
 gnb = GaussianNB()
 y_pred = gnb.fit(iris.data, iris.target).predict(iris.data)
 print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (iris.data.shape[0],(iris.target != y_pred).sum()))

 mnb = MultinomialNB()
 y_pred_mnb = mnb.fit(iris.data, iris.target).predict(iris.data)
 print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (iris.data.shape[0],(iris.target != y_pred_mnb).sum()))

 bnb = BernoulliNB()
 y_pred_bnb = bnb.fit(iris.data, iris.target).predict(iris.data)
 print("Number of mislabeled points out of a total %d points : %d" % (iris.data.shape[0],(iris.target !=    y_pred_bnb).sum()))
```

Output looks like :
     Number of mislabeled points out of a total 150 points : 6
     Number of mislabeled points out of a total 150 points : 7
     Number of mislabeled points out of a total 150 points : 100

Bernoulli Naive Bayes classifier mislabels 100 which is way more than the others. Can you please explain why ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a nutshell, the **Gaussian Naive Bayes** model is generally used for continuous data (where each feature is a real number), where the underlying data distribution is assumed to be a Gaussian (Normal) distribution.

The **Multinomial Naive Bayes** model *counts* how often a certain event occurs in the dataset (for example how often a certain word occurs in a document).

The **Bernoulli Naive Bayes** model is similar to the Multinomial Naive Bayes model, but instead of counting how often an event occurred, it only describes whether or not an event occurred (for example whether or not a certain word occurs in a document, where it doesn't matter if it occurs once or 100000 times)

Now specifically for the iris dataset, which contains real valued data, the `GaussianNB` would be the most suitable model. A classic example of where the `MultinomialNB` would be most appropriate is Text classification.

So given the characteristics of your dataset and each model, it is not surprising that the Bernoulli Naive Bayes model didn't do very well. The larger surprise is that the Multinomial Naive Bayes model did almost as well as the Gaussian model even though its an inappropriate choice for this dataset (real valued data). However looking at the data (I encourage you to do it) should give you the right hint why the Multinomial Naive Bayes model could achieve such a good performance.

For an in-depth comparison of the Bernoulli Naive Bayes model and the Multinomial Naive Bayes model for Text classification I would suggest you read [this](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.46.1529) paper.

You might also want to check the excellent [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/naive_bayes.html) on Naive Bayes for an overview of the different models, and last but not least, the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naive_Bayes_classifier) on the Naive Bayes Classifier gives an excellent overview as well.

**Update:**

As `mbatchkarov` points out in the comment below, you are testing and training on the same data which is considered *very* bad practice and therefore definite conclusions cannot be drawn from the above results. Consider using [cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html) or at least splitting the data into a training chunk and a testing chunk.

Comment: I would also add that definitive conclusions should not be drawn on the basis of the code above. At the very least one should not be testing on the training data. Ideally, some type of cross validation should have been employed.